# Create resilient require mechanism in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, require, npm-install

I have an application and I want it to be resilient against missing dependencies. Some sort of fallback mechanism, in case a dependency is missing or corrupted.

So I have this, which monkey-patches require() and in theory will re-install a dependency if it cannot be loaded the first time:

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const Mod = require('module');
const req = Mod.prototype.require;
Mod.prototype.require = function (d) {

  try {
    return req.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  catch (e) {
    if (/^[A-Za-z]/.test(String(d))) {
      console.error(`could not require dependency "${d}".`);
      try {
        var actualDep = String(d).split('/')[0];
        console.error(`but we are resilient and we are attempting to install "${actualDep}" now.`);
        cp.execSync(`cd ${_suman.projectRoot} && npm install ${actualDep}`);
        return req.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.error('\n', err.stack || err, '\n');
        throw e;
      }

    }
    else {
      throw e;
    }
  }

};
```

but the above patch is not working as expected. The problem is that the initial try statement:

```
return req.apply(this, arguments);
```

it mostly works, but it's doing some strange things..for example, it starts installing

```
bufferutil
utf-8-validate
```

this doesn't make sense to me, because require() works without any errors normally, but when using the patch, require() suddenly fails.

Anyone know what might be going on? Super weird.

(Note what it's doing is only attempting to re-install dependencies that start with a character [a-zA-z], it won't attempt to install a dependency that starts with './' etc.)

Comment: Maybe someone else is "require"ing a module if it's there, and swallowing the exception if not? Might be interesting to see a stack trace showing who's calling your monkey-patched "require" whenever you hit the "dependency missing" condition.

Comment: ahh very smart, good thinking, I will create a stack trace

Comment: I think what I am going is not that great of an idea :) I can't really ever be sure if something is supposed to throw or not.

Comment: Agreed, it seems like a risky thing to do. Maybe you could do this for packages on a whitelist, or those already listed in your package.json, but it might not be a good idea for everything.

Comment: yeah I am thinking just a select set, and I will probably just surround with try/catch manually, oh well, thanks for the feedback, will leave the question up for reference.